# yum update is failing in centos 8

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, yum

I have a redhat.repo file which points to a list of rpms. This repo has different versions of nginx. Currently in this machine, I'm nginx 1.10. My requirement is to update nginx to 1.14. I have confirmed that I have nginx 1.14 rpm in my repo. This is what I'm facing

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum list installed | grep nginx
nginx-filesystem.noarch                                         1:1.10.1-9         @AppStream_x86_64_os
```

When I try to update, I am getting "Dependencies resolved, Nothing todo"

```
 [root@localhost ~]# yum update nginx-filesystem.noarch
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
extras_x86_64_os                                                                                 65 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
BaseOS_x86_64_os                                                                                 65 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
cr_x86_64_os                                                                                     58 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
AppStream_x86_64_os                                                                              61 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:00
RT_x86_64_os                                                                                     57 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
PowerTools_x86_64_os                                                                             56 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
centosplus_x86_64_os                                                                             52 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
HighAvailability_x86_64_os                                                                       51 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
Devel_x86_64_os                                                                                  59 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: Try yum install nginx?

Comment: tried. It says nginx is already installed.

Comment: nginx-[versions] are in the AppStream repo  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/ ........ Please use `dnf search nginx` to decide version to install.

Comment: Didnt worked. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

dnf module update worked. Listed and found out the versions and did dnf module install package-name